# D3 - how do I remove comma separator from my xAxis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, formatting

I have a data set that uses straightforward dates for the x-axis. However, I keep getting a comma separator in the thousands place (which would lend some confusion to my graph's intent.) I can't seem to figure out how to word my .format line properly.

Original code:

```
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);
```

My .formatted scale:

```
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .format(04d);
```

The second option -- you guessed it -- makes my whole graph disappear. Any takers?

Comment: Is your 04d inside double quotes? ```.format("04d")```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `04d` in quotes. It should be a string.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([0, width])
     .format("04d");
```

Read more about [formatting in the d3 docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).

By the way, your chart probably disappeared because without the quotes, `04d` is a syntax error. Your browser's development tools should show you such an error, so make sure you check them. It's really handy to have them open while developing.